# Memory leak in Location manager

Tags: android, memory-leaks, location, leakcanary

In my application's splash screen, I'm starting to listen the location via gps or network until my second activity opens.

my network location listener:

```
private LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            newLocationReceived(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
```

my gps location listener:

```
private LocationListener locationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            newLocationReceived(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
```

Inside onCreate I call getLocation method, for permissions I use rxPermission:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getLocation() {
        rxPermissions
                .request(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .subscribe(granted -> {
                    if (granted) {
                        boolean gpsEnabled, networkEnabled;

                        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            networkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                            if (gpsEnabled && locationListenerGPS != null) {
                                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0L, 0f, locationListenerGPS);
                            }

                            if (networkEnabled && locationListenerNetwork != null) {
                                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0L, 0f, locationListenerNetwork);
                            }
                        }


                    } else {
                        Timber.e("LOCATION PERMISSION DENIED");
                    }
                });
    }
```

When new location is received I call:

```
private void newLocationReceived(Location location) {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGPS);
        }
        locationManager = null;
        this.location = location;
    }
```

And in order to avoid memory leaks I call this method in onPause, onStop and onDestroy:

```
private void stopLocationListener() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGPS);
            locationManager = null;
        }
        if (locationListenerNetwork != null) locationListenerNetwork = null;
        if (locationListenerGPS != null) locationListenerGPS = null;
    }
```

However, In order to LeakCanary I still get memory leaks in location manager. How can I resolve this? Also sometimes My splash screen passes the progresses too fast and my runtime permission can stay at background too

Comment: how did you fix this?